# WP home page redirect to wp-login

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins, wordpress-theming, wp-admin

I try to go to the site([https://worldcalling4me.com/](https://stackoverflow.com)) but it redirects me to wp-login([https://worldcalling4me.com/login.php](https://stackoverflow.com)).
I find that it gives me 302 for the site ([https://worldcalling4me.com/](https://stackoverflow.com)).
I try everything like cache clear,.htaccess delete, cookies clear but it does not solve.I also try to use a fresh copy of wp but does not resolve.
It only work happen for laptop and tablet but work well for mobile.

please help me

When go to [https://worldcalling4me.com/](https://stackoverflow.com) it will got to site home([https://worldcalling4me.com/](https://stackoverflow.com)).